# Hex to int conversion in C

Tags: c, hex

I am trying to build my own function that converts from Hex number to decimal integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 30

/* this code will conver string hexo number to integer */


int myhtoi(char[]);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char heX[SIZE];
    scanf("%s", heX);

    printf("%d", myhtoi(heX));
    return 0;
}

int myhtoi(char input[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int result = 0;

    for(i = strlen(input); i >= 0;i --)
    {
        if((input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'f') || (input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'F'))
        {
            switch (input[i])
            {
            case 'a':
                num = 10;
                break;
                
            case 'b':
                num = 11;
                break;
            
            case 'c':
                num = 12;
                break;
            
            case 'd':
                num = 13;
                break;

            case 'e':
                num = 14;
                break;

            case 'f':
                num = 15;
                break;

            case 'A':
                num = 10;
                break;
                
            case 'B':
                num = 11;
                break;
            
            case 'C':
                num = 12;
                break;
            
            case 'D':
                num = 13;
                break;

            case 'E':
                num = 14;
                break;

            case 'F':
                num = 15;
                break;
            
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        num = input[i];
        printf("%d\n", num);
        printf("%c\n", input[i]);
        result = result + num;
    }

    return result;

}
```

My logic was that when the input was inserted, it read it from at the end of char array and scan all the way to the front.

However, it gives me incorrect outputs.
I thought I may not have a perfect understanding of how char and integer work in C.

Can someone advise me where are my issues in this code?

Comment: you missed the else condition

Comment: `strtol (ptr, &endptr, 0)` is another quick way to handle octal and hex conversions. (after your exercise -- which is a good one)

Comment: note that character `'1'` is **not** an integer `1`

Comment: You can replace your `switch` statement with `num=tolower(input[i]) - 'a' + 10`

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```c
else
   num = input[i] - '0';
```

instead of

```c
num = input[i] - '0';
```

You could also have it as your default in your switch instead (and no need to check if its between 'a' and 'z' and 'A' and 'Z'):

```
switch (tolower(input[i]))
            {
            case 'a':
                num = 10;
                break;
                
            case 'b':
                num = 11;
                break;
            
            case 'c':
                num = 12;
                break;
            
            case 'd':
                num = 13;
                break;

            case 'e':
                num = 14;
                break;

            case 'f':
                num = 15;
                break;

            default:
                num = input[i] - '0';
                break;
            }
```

More importantly, **you also have to convert the digit from a char to an integer, '0' is a char and 0 is it's corresponding value**.

Refer to the ASCII table, `'0'` is at position `48`, or `0x30`, so substracting either `'0', 48 or 0x30` will give you the right corresponding value.

NB: This assume that you got a valid input (only letters from a to f, upper or lower cases, and digits).

Comment: I did the way you suggest which I managed to get the letter to an integer. However, I am still not getting integer to integer. a -> 10 b->11 but 1 ->0

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

```
for(i = strlen(input); i >= 0;i --)
```

`strlen()` returns the number of characters before the terminating NUL, so after `i = strlen(input)`, `input[i]` is that NUL. Probably not the character you want to process. You are doing `printf("%c\n", input[i]);` in there, but the NUL byte usually doesn't print visibly, so it may be hard to miss.

```
if((input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'f') || (input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'F'))
```

What if it's not a valid hex letter? Actually, what if it's not a valid hex letter *and* not a digit either? You need to handle invalid input somehow.

```
num = input[i];
```

This looks to be unconditional, and overwrites whatever that switch set. Besides, it takes the character code of `input[i]`, not the numerical value of the corresponding number. Like `'A'` is `0x41`, `'1'` is `0x31` etc. You need to also convert the digits `0-9` to numbers, the same you did for `a-f`.

```
result = result + num;
```

Doesn't this just sum the digits without regard to their position? That is, `111` would give 3, not 256+16+1. Every time you move one character to the left, the value of that digit gets multiplied by 16.

---

I suggest you:

- Split getting the numerical value of a single digit to a separate function, something like `int hexdigit(char c)`, which you can implement in any way you like. Then test that it returns the correct values, i.e. 1 for `1`, 10 for `a` and `A` etc.
- Do the number parsing from left to right instead of right to left. That way, you can just multiply the value this far by 16 every time you get the next valid digit. That is, `123` would be read as 1, then 16*1+2 = 18, then 16*18+3 = 291.
  You can do it in the other direction too, but you need to have the base-16 factor of the "current" digit somewhere.
- Check and re-check the indexing, so that you don't process the NUL or anything outside the string.
- Then, do something about invalid input. Either have `hexdigit()` give an error value for invalid characters, or have another function check it. In either case, check that in the main loop, and do something sensible. E.g. if the input is `12x4`, you probably don't want neither the `x` nor the `4` to influence the returned value.